# Unable to persist data using Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I am unable to persist the data using spring and hibernate. I looked at various post and tried many things. But it just doesn't work.
I ll post my config first and then the steps I tried. Would appreciate any help.

spring-jpa.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.gamelist.dao.classes" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

GenericDAO.java

```
public class GenericDaoJPA<T extends IDomainObject> implements IGenericDao<T> {

protected EntityManager entityManager;

@PersistenceContext
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager){
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

    public void save(T object) throws DataAccessException{
    entityManager.persist(object);
}
.
.
. 
.
}
```

User.java (Domain)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable, IDomainObject{
private long id;
private String firstName;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public final long getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id){
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
}
```

TestService.java (UserDao implements IUserDao and extends GenericDao)

```
@Service(value = "testService")
@Transactional
public class TestService implements ITestService {
 @Autowired
private IUserDao userDao;

@Transactional(readOnly = false)
public void saveUser(User newUser){
    userDao.save(newUser);
}
.
.
.
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="gamelistPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
        <!--
            value='create' to build a new database on each run;
            value='update' to modify an existing database;
            value='create-drop' means the same as 'create' but also drops tables when Hibernate closes;
            value='validate' makes no changes to the database
         -->
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

I do not get any errors or exceptions or anything. I am able to read from my database. Only update, add or delete do not persist.

Here is all what I tried

1. One post mentioned changing transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" to JTA saying that RESOURCE_LOCAL does not persist at all. I think this is if you are using only hibernate and not managing your transactions while using RESOURCE_LOCAL. I believe spring manages the transactions for you.
2. Some mentioned doing em.flush or em.getTransaction.begin and commit after using persist. But I get this error every time I use the above mentioned operations.
   Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your UserDao class?

Comment: Try use `@PersistenceUnit` as mentioned [here](http://tomee.apache.org/jpa-concepts.html) when using `transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL`

Comment: What's the code which is calling all this and not persisting?

Answer (score 0):

It's a failure to commit the TX (or flush Hibernate). Your declarative transactionality isn't working, or the declarations needs to be extended further.

Shouldn't the DAO be declared as tranasactional?  That's where the action actually happens, your "transactional" declaration at TestService doesn't actually do anything itself -- so Spring may miss enlisting HB into the transaction.

I don't generally use declarative, myself, since I find TX boundaries easy & well-defined on user activity -- and more traceable/ reliable when explicitly coded (1 line, via my helper class).

Frankly I don't know what you expect to do with your DAOs either -- if you're using JPA/ Hibernate, these layers handle what the DAO would do. I suspect you're gunking up your application with do-nothing classes, the proper purpose/ use of which you don't understand.

What's wrong with:

```
Session hb = HbHelper.session();
hb.save( user);
HbHelper.commit();  // commits via a TX.
```

I use this style with an "OpenSessionInView" Filter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually setting up using a tutorial as a reference. From my understanding DAO layer is basically used to run specific queries on specific objects (in this case user). And doesn't the entitymanager do the same as what you did behind the scene? I tried making the DAO transactional as well. But the issue still happened.

Comment: There are several ways of integrating Spring and Hibernate. Personally, I put significant units of business logic in a User Service & trivial stuff, like calling `entityManager.save()`, I avoid adding excess layers to. My approach is to do it "in front of the scenes", as it were.

Comment: Good for trying making DAO transactional, pity it didn't work. Search Google for "how to debug spring declarative transactions" & you'll find some guides. Presumably Hibernate isn't enlisted, for some reason.. you'll need to investigate yourself, this is beyond my personal experience.